# CentOS 6 не работает интернет после установки XRDP

Tags: linux, centos

Взял для работы VDS 256 RAM, чисто символически, установил XRDP, подключаюсь, всё ок, вот только иконка связи с интернетом перечеркнута, в браузере ничего не грузит, в терминале все команды связанные с интернетом так же не работают. Не знаю что делать, тех. поддержка помогать отказывается. да, самое интересное что сам сервер доступен по SSh т.е. нормально подключается к нему.

После установки XRDP я перезагрузил сервер, и интернет перестает работать.
Устанавливал я так:

> yum -y upgrade
>
> yum -y install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-fonts-truetype
>
> yum -y groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop"
>
> rpm -Uvh
>   http://fedora.ip-connect.vn.ua/fedora-epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
>
> yum -y install xrdp yum -y install tigervnc tigervnc-server
>   tigervnc-server-module
>
> chkconfig haldaemon --levels 2345 off
>
> chkconfig xrdp --levels 345 on service xrdp start

После перезагрузки проверяю, и вот:

```
[root@vm~]# wget vk.com
--2015-12-01 04:46:42--  http://vk.com/
Resolving vk.com... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address `vk.com'
```

До установки всё работало.

UPD:
вывод `$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 242 Dec  1 06:05 /etc/resolv.conf
```

вывод `$ cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search hv8.ru


# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
```

команда ping 8.8.8.8 работает

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=2.68 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=2.53 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=2.59 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=2.30 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=2.37 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=58 time=2.45 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=58 time=2.52 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=58 time=2.30 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=58 time=2.87 ms
```

UPD:
нашел на подобии таких, `ifcfg-venet0:0` пробовал добавлять во все, без толку, после перезагрузки сети сервер не отвечает, и его нужно перезагружать полностью...
почему после установки XRDP всё сбивается?

ПОЧТИ РЕШИЛ: вообщем дошло до того что я тупо скопировал файл resolv.conf с только что установленного дистрибутива, а после настройки заменил, иконка по прежднему показывает что соединения нет, но интернет работает, только вот после перезагрузки этот файл заменяется на старый, и опять ничего не работает...

Comment: если пропинговать по адресу любой сервак, допустим ping 8.8.8.8, и все будет нормально, тогда вопрос DNS и следует поправить файлик /etc/resolv.conf, на предмет серверов DNS.

Comment: приложите к вопросу вывод команд: `$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` и `$ cat /etc/resolv.conf`. внести исправления можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

судя по содержимому файла `/etc/resolv.conf`, его содержимым управляют скрипты *networkmanager-а*.

в нём же есть и подсказка, где именно и в каком виде следует вписать *nameserver-ы*:

в один из `ifcfg*` файлов в каталоге `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`. скорее всего, это будет `ifcfg-eth0`.

если провайдер/хостер не предоставил вам адреса своих внутренних *nameserver-ов*, можете воспользоваться публичными от *google*:

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

---

после добавления этих строк сеть надо перезапустить. примерно так:

```
$ sudo service network restart
```

Answer (score -1):

Та же проблема встречается на некоторых плохих хостингах.
А всё дело оказалось в NetworkManager - его просто нужно перезапустить:

```
service network restart
```

Вот и всё.